# Period.between (rounding day) during a period that includes daylight saving in Java 8

Tags: java

I have a problem that I can not resolve in a elegant way. 
I need to have the number of dates between 2 days in Java 8 (without JodaTime) but rounding up the day.
Code explains better than me (Dates are not parsed)

The localDateTime I wanted to know the difference between 2015-03-20/00:00 to 2015-04-06/00:00 but transform to utc is easier to see.

```
    ZoneDateTime startLocalDate="2015-03-19T23:00Z[UTC]";
 ZoneDateTime  endLocaldate="2015-04-05T22:00Z[UTC]"; 
Period betweenDates =  Period.between( startLocalDate, endLocalDate); 
    long days = betweenDates.getDays();
```

> 16 days  but in really it is 16 days 23 hours (That is correct)

I can change the code to make it works all year perfect adding one hour(plusHours(1))

```
ZoneDateTime startLocalDate="2015-03-19T23:00Z[UTC]";
ZoneDateTime endLocaldate="2015-04-05T22:00Z[UTC]";
Period betweenDates = Period.between( startLocalDate, endLocalDate.plusHours(1));
long days = betweenDates.getDays();
```

> this produces 17 days that I need for reporting

There is any more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Don't use `Period.between(...).getDays()` if you want the total number of days (try with `2015-01-01` and `2015-02-02` - 1 day). To get total days, use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()`

Comment: I think also `endLocalDate.toEpochDay() - startLocalDate.toEpochDay()` should work too.

Comment: Also your first example is giving me 17 days (using `LocalDate.parse("...")`). LocalDate doesn't even store time, so it doesn't have `plusHours()`. Are you using a different class?

Comment: Cinnam, why I should use ChronoUnits instead Period? and it is not working because return 16 days, not the 17 days I need.
The option toEpochDay didt work too.

Sorry, i was using ZoneDateTime and where I can add the hours to adjust.

Comment: @Guel135 because if the period is 2 months 3 days, `Period#getDays()` will just return 3. Can you post the full code that gives you 16 days? Your first example above is giving me 17.

Comment: @Cinnam, I had add to the second part of code the dateTime to UTC it is easier to see, delete the plusHour(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LocalDate` doesn't store time or timezone information, so it's unaffected by DST. If you have e.g. `ZonedDateTime` as source and you are only interested in dates, you can get the dates with `toLocalDate()`. Then you can get the number of days between the two dates:

```
    ZonedDateTime dt1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-03-19T23:00Z");
    ZonedDateTime dt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-04-05T22:00Z");

    LocalDate startLocalDate = dt1.toLocalDate();
    LocalDate endLocalDate = dt2.toLocalDate();
    long expectedNumDocuments = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startLocalDate, endLocalDate);
    System.out.println(expectedNumDocuments); // 17
```

You also have to use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` instead of `Period#between()`, since the latter will not get you the total number of days (try with `2015-01-01` and `2015-02-02`, `Period#getDays()` will return 1, when in fact the period is 1 month 1 day).

Comment: Sorry, I was checking and the code is huge but it seems to work.
Thank you!!

Comment: Great sollution! with LocalTime give me my 17 days but with dateTime give me 16. I should use LocalTime

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to calculate from the start of day A to the end of day B.  You should be able to do this with

```
Period.between(startLocalDate, 
               endLocalDate.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay().toLocalDate());
```

By adding an entire day, then moving back to midnight, you avoid the need to calculate how many hours need adding.

In fact, you could probably skip the `atStartOfDay` because as you've already seen, the hours will be disregarded.  That's your call.

Comment: This will generate a problem when you are in Autumn daylights